# issue with trying to set up virtual environment with pipenv

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I would really appreciate any help for pipenv.

I have installed using `pip3` and have created an empty folder to test the virtual environment process.

But, for some reason when I run the command `pipenv --three` on the folder `project-3`, I get the following output:

```
`Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will 
automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set 
PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own 
instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Creating a Pipfile for this project…`
```

So, the command does run and a virtual environment is set up as the `Pipfile` is created and is located within the folder.

However, the python version is set to 2.7 (check below) for some reason even though I have used the option `--three`.

```
`[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
[dev-packages]
[packages]
[requires]
python_version = "2.7"`
```

Please bear in mind that I'm a beginner programmer and still learning.

Why does the 'courtesy notice' above say that it found itself running within a virtual environment?

Do I need to set `PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1` and how do I do this if this is the case?

Thanks again and I would really appreciate any advice or suggestions :)

Comment: Just to add more information, I have had the same problem. I have tried to run the followin command but still end up with 2.7 on my Pipfile
    python3 -m pipenv --python 3.7

Comment: So this fixed it for me, although it is not the proper way by any means. I opened the Pipfile created and changed 2.7 to 3.7 which is the version I have installed. I then run pipenv shell so that it creates the enviroment.